# How are instructions embedded in the processor and boards of a computer

Tags: data-structures, architecture, embedded

So, the processor has a clock that turns on and off which is a predetermined instruction. How are these instructions loaded into the processor as instructions? I am just visualizing a clean slate with the CPU how do we teach or tell the CPU to do what it does?

Also, if we are at a clean slate how do we load the data into a computer to recognize binary?

I'm sorry if this is an overload on questions, I'm just super curious..

Comment: Your question is way too broad. And: you can easily do some research on that. And hint: instructions can be **implemented** in hardware. There is no need to **load** instructions, when they are hard-wired into the CPU. One of many links to start with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting

Comment: I shall check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instruction execution starts at a hardwired address known as the *reset vector*.  The instructions are programmed in memory; the means by which that is done varies depending on the memory technology used and the type of processor.

For standalone CPUs with no on-chip memory, the initial code will normally be in some kind of external *read-only random-access memory (ROM)* often called a *bootrom* - this for example is the BIOS on a PC motherboard.  On modern platforms these ROMs normally use a technology known as *NOR Flash* which can be electrically erased and reprogrammed, either by loading them on a dedicated programmer or in-circuit (so for example a PC can rewrite its own BIOS flash).

For *microcontrollers (MCU)* with on-chip memory, these often have on-chip flash ROM and can also be electrically programmed typically using an on-chip programming and debug interface known as a *JTAG interface* (proprietary interfaces also exist on some devices).  Some MCUs include *mask ROM* that is not rewritable which contains a simple (or *primary*) bootloader.  Usually you can select how an MCU boots.

The job of the bootloader is to load more complex code into memory (electrically programmable ROM or RAM) and execute it.  Often a primary bootloader in mask ROM is too simple and restricted to do very much, and will load a more complete bootloader that then loads an OS.  For example a common scenario is for an processor to have a primary bootloader that loads code from a simple non-random access memory such as NAND flash or SD card; this may then load a more fully featured bootloader such as UBOOT typically used to load Linux for example.  This *secondary* bootloader can support more complex devices boot sources such as a hard-disk, network, CD, USB.

Answer (score 0):

Typically CPU's used to read either address zero or 0xFFFF-(address length-1) (add F's if your address room is larger) and take that as the start address of the boot loader.

There is also the possibility that the CPU starts by loading a micro code into the CPU and then starts the real assembler code from a predetermined address.